# Resizing command changes image shape

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have to resize image i.e if its dimension is 3456x5184 to 700X700 as my code needs image with less number of pixels otherwise it takes too much time to give results.So, when I use imresize command it changes the dimensions of image but at the same time it changes the shape of image i.e the circle in image which I also need to detect looks like oval instead of being cirle. I need your suggestions to resolve this problem. I am really grateful to you people.

Comment: If you change from *3500-by-5000* to *700-by-700*, the image will be stretched, as you change it from rectangular to square. If you want a non-distorted square image, you'll have to crop it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing images is done by either subsampling (to get smaller images) or some kind of interpolation (to get larger images)

Input is either a factor or a final dimension for width and height.

The only way to fit a rectangle into a square by simply resizing it is to use different scales for width and height. Which of course will yield in a distorted image.

To achieve what you want you can either crop a 700x700 region from your image or  resize image using the same factor for with and height. Then you can fit the larger dimension into 700 and fill the rest around the other dimension with black or whatever you prefer.